# How should I export http_proxy variable?

Tags: bash, networking, proxy

I'm trying to write a simple script that will set proxy settings. Actually I just need to export `http_proxy ftp_proxy https_proxy ...` variables with `export` command.
But it's not working when I run it manually from the shell because `export` affect only current shell and subshells, but no others. Also I don't want to call it from `.bashrc` because it's not my default proxy settings.

So how should I export `http_proxy` variable to make effect globally?

Comment: No access to `~/.bashrc` at all?

Comment: @Cthulhu sorry for my English. I have access to `~/.bashrc` but I don't want to edit it every time I need to disable proxy settings.

Answer (score 21):

Back in the day I was also sick of setting and then unsetting the proxy settings after my work was done.  I always wished if there was a command simple command to do the set and unset function for me.

Then I figured that if I create a new function in my .bashrc I can call it from the command line by using the bash-tab-completion.  Saves even more time.

This is what I did:

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc
function setproxy() {
    export {http,https,ftp}_proxy='http://proxy-serv:8080'
}

function unsetproxy() {
    unset {http,https,ftp}_proxy
}

$ . ~/.bashrc
```

Now I just do:

```
$ setproxy
```

or

```
$ setp<TAB> and <ENTER>
```

and it sets the proxy for me.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this in a script, make this a function.  You can declare this function in your `.bashrc`:

```
function set_custom_proxy() {
  export http_proxy='http://myproxy:3128'
}
```

Then run this in the current shell:

```
echo $http_proxy
set_custom_proxy
echo $http_proxy
```

It works as a variable modification in a function is not local to the function.

**EDIT**:

FYI: to use a local variable in a function, you need to use the `local` keyword:

```
atest="Hello World"
btest="Hello World2"
function my_func() {
  local atest;
  atest="Hello World3"
  btest="Hello World4"
  echo $atest
  echo $btest
}
echo $atest
echo $btest
my_func
echo $atest
echo $btest
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't access `.bashrc`, you can use `source` command which will run in the current shell's context and all the variables you set will be available.

```
source ./script
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the .bashrc file run your script with `.`

```
. script.sh
```